# Editing files from different git branches

Tags: git

I am verry new to git. I cloned a project on my local server and I edit my files with TextMate.

So, I had a branch called master. Then I created a second branch called local. I made somes modifications, added some files and commited them all. But now when I go back to my master branch, I am unable to edit with TextMate the ancient files (non modified master branch files). How is it possible to fix that? Am I supposed not to use TextMate?

Best,
Mehdi

Comment: Could just be a permissions error. Git won't prevent you from editing the files...

Comment: But when I look at my files with files on my mac, they correspond to the newest version. It seems I can t use TextMate to edit, no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you do something like this then:

```
#clone out repo that only has master branch
git clone path/to/repo

#create and checkout branch local
git checkout -b"local"

## edit files ###

#stage files
git add .

#commit changes
git commit -m"did some work"

#switch back to master
git checkout master
```

At this point you should be on your local master branch as you were after clone. If you want to merge in your changes from local into master:

```
git merge local
```

At any point you can run `git status` to see which files have changed and `git branch -a` to see all of the branches on your repo

If you did all of this correctly and still cant edit the files then it could be a permissions issue:

```
sudo chmod 644 /path/to/local/files/* -R
```

Comment: I made it just like you said, point by point. But for example when I run an ls command after having switched, I find all the files I added when I worked on my local branch. How is it possible?

Comment: Just one point I didn t merged the two branches because I don t want to do that for the moment

Comment: ok if the files are untracked by git then they will stay in place when you switch branches as they are not controlled by git. you would first need to commit them. So for example if you cloned out the repo, added files and then switched branches without committing those files then the files will follow you around until you commit them to a branch. If you run a git status you will see these files under the heading: Untracked files:

Comment: So I didn t merge them but I commited them!

Comment: So it can only be a permission issue. I ll let you know

Comment: So in fact I made the step by step worflow and I went wrong, I made a typing error : "git chekout". I forgot the c, so I didn t switch of branch and I had the impression that my output was desperatly the same. I am so sorry to have bother ypu for such a silly thing...

Answer (score 1):

So here is the some usefull commands

suppose you are on master branch then you created newbranch

$git checkout -b newbranch

then edit some files here then you need to commit that changes

$git add .
$git commit -m "commit message"

then switch to master branch

$git checkout master

merge the changes

$git merge newbranch

Answer (score 0):

I always need to edit like that. By way of illustration, I conjure up something important and need to jog them down immediately in a file A which is not in the branch I'm on while editing a file B which is unfinished to commit, what I do is like the following:

```
# stage and commit the fileB
git add fileB; git commit -m 'uncompleted'

# checkout to the branch containing file A
git checkout branchA

# editting the file A

# stage and commit the fileA
git add fileA; git commit -m 'big idea'

# go back to the first branch
git checkout branchB

# reset to the previous commit without changing the working-spot
git reset --soft HEAD~

# edit again and commit 
git add fileB; git commit -m 'extend the previous commit'
```

Now it's just like as if the interrupt of my untimely brainstrom were not happened for the file B. Always feel free to edit in diffrent branches.